# Internet Explorer Version Suffix: CO

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I was checking my Internet explorer version after hearing about a big security bug in IE and I noticed that IE stated the following information:

Version: 11.0.9600.17105 **CO**

Update Versions: 11.0.7 (KB2964358)

...

I couldn't find any information about what the CO at the end of my version meant. Does it mean that I have an older version of IE and need to update it (I have automatic version install checked)? Or does it indicate some sort of setting I have on IE?

Comment: I think this question is better suited to http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that means it's a Corporate edition of IE, customised using the IEAK (Microsoft Internet Explorer Administration Kit). See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393 for more information.

As far as I'm aware this has no bearing on how pages are rendered, unless certain things have been switched off as part of the IEAK customisation (e.g. DirectX filters - although that won't be relevant for IE11).

Comment: This can effect the way pages are rendered via the `SiteList`.  It takes highest precedent when rendering pages and can force IE emulation that differs from the x-ua-compatible metadata in both the page, and the site's config (in `web.config` for example).